# create a custom root in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a resource called bus_companies

```
resources :bus_companies
```

This generates URl  as  `bus_companies/`,   `bus_companies/show`, etc.  But I need that the url to be  `companies/`, `companies/show`, etc.  And I don't want change the name of the controller to Companies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this in your `config/routes.rb` file

```
resources :bus_companies, path: "companies"
```

You can read more about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)